# Spring RestTemplate post using parameters in a HashMap throws 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When I use Spring `RestTemplate.postForObject` to post parameters using `HashMap`, server throws 400 Bad Request:

```
Map<String, Object> uriVariables = new HashMap<>();
uriVariables.put("param1", "param1val");
restTemplate.postForObject(url, uriVariables, responseType);
```

Log:

```
14:51:20.102 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Created POST request for "http://localhost:8080/demo-1/test"
14:51:20.113 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Setting request Accept header to [text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*]
14:51:20.161 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Writing [{param1=1}] using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@8e24743]
14:51:20.225 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - POST request for "http://localhost:8080/demo-1/test" resulted in 400 (null); invoking error handler
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 null
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:78)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:700)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:653)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:380)
```

But if I use `MultiValueMap`, it works.

```
MultiValueMap<String, Object> uriVariables = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
uriVariables.add("param1", "param1val");
restTemplate.postForObject(url, uriVariables, responseType);
```

Log:

```
14:52:08.493 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Created POST request for "http://localhost:8080/demo-1/test"
14:52:08.501 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Setting request Accept header to [text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*]
14:52:08.502 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Writing [{param1=[1]}] using [org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter@4abdb505]
14:52:08.537 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - POST request for "http://localhost:8080/demo-1/test" resulted in 200 (null)
14:52:08.539 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Reading [java.lang.String] as "text/plain;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@13c27452]
{"name":"1"}
```

Here is controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(name = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String test(@RequestParam("param1") final String param1) {
    // some class Test
    final Test test = new Test();
    test.setName(param1);
    return JsonUtils.toJson(test);
}
```

Can somebody explain why passing request parameters using a `HashMap` doesn't work?

Comment: The second snippet is wrong and does not compile - `MultiValueMap::put` method accepts list of values, not single one: `public List<V> put(K key, List<V> value)`. Did you make mistake?

Comment: Sorry, It was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

When you say : `it throws 400 Bad Request:` do you understand what is referred by `it` ? hint : it is not Spring REST client code, but the server you are talking to, which do not accept your http request as valid.

You could activate logging of the httpclient implementation used by spring restTemplate to see how going from `HashMap` to `LinkedMultiValueMap` change the generated http request.

You also could look at spring restTemplate source code to see why generate different requests.

EDIT: the important part of the log you've posted :

> 14:51:20.161 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Writing [{param1=1}] using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@8e24743]

here it is writing json most certainly on the http request body

while with LinkedMultiValueMap :

> 14:52:08.502 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Writing [{param1=[1]}] using [org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter@4abdb505]

in the first case, your request won't have a parameter `param1` but all data in the request body, while in the second case, you get a `param1` parameter, making the request valid for the server

It should be possible to configure `RestTemplate` by extending / creating a message converter to work the way you want with a `HashMap`, but I advise you to stay with `LinkedMultiValueMap` for 2 reasons :

- this is the default spring settings. So you will have an easier migration when you'll need to update to next versions.
- other people using your code won't be surprised by the "new" way RestTemplate is working with your custom configuration

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any way to make `HashMap` work with post requests, as `MultiValueMap` is there for multiple values against a single parameter, which I don't need. I just want to pass single value against a single parameter. Otherwise I will be using `MultiValueMap` all over the places.

Answer (score 1):

MultiValueMap has different value type than HashMap. It can be seen in its interface definition:

```
interface MultiValueMap<K, V> extends Map<K, List<V>>
```

and HashMap:

```
class HashMap<K,V> extends AbstractMap<K,V>
```

You use `put` method to fill HashMap and `add` method to fill MultiValueMap, so it looks similar, but in fact MultiValueMap holds **lists**, not single values. It can be seen in your logs:

HashMap:

> 14:51:20.161 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate
>   - Writing [{param1=1}]

MultiValueMap:

> 14:52:08.502 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate
>   - Writing [{param1=[1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#postForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object...-)}]

As you see `{param1=1}` does not work and `{param1=[1]}` works.

Additionally, in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#postForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object...-) of `RestTemplate` it is recommended to use MultiValueMap:

> The body of the entity, or request itself, can be a MultiValueMap to
>   create a multipart request. The values in the MultiValueMap can be any
>   Object representing the body of the part, or an HttpEntity
>   representing a part with body and headers. The MultiValueMap can be
>   built conveniently using MultipartBodyBuilder.

Comment: Thanks for answer. My request is not a multipart request. Also, I don't wan't to use a `MultiValueMap` as I don't need multiple values against a single parameter. So just wanted to get it working using `HashMap`.

Comment: Did you try the simplest solution as using `HashMap<String, List<Object>>` instead of `HashMap<String, Object>`?

Comment: Yes tried using `HashMap<String, List<Object>>`. Still same 400 exception. What I obeserved is when I use `HashMap` it uses `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`, but when I use `MultiValueMap` it uses `AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter`.

Answer (score 0):

You choice to use `HttpHeaders` and `HttpEntity` and `MultiValueMap` or `hashMap`. you look up this keyword and link. may be useful.

[RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html)

[HttpHeaders](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders.html)

[HttpEntity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpEntity.html)

[MultiValueMap](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/MultiValueMap.html)

**This is sample code :**

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

headers.add("x-sample-session-id", sampleService.getServerSessionId());

MultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();


map.add("file", new ByteArrayResource(model.getFile().getBytes()));
map.add("apList", model.getApList());

HttpEntity<?> request = new HttpEntity<Object>(map, headers);

String url = sampleService.getContextPath() + "/thirdParty/" + sampleService.getThirdPartyId() + "/child/"
        + childId + "/location?sessionId=" + childSessionId
        + "&op=sendOnDemandLocationResponseWithPhoto&latitude=" + latitude + "&longitude=" + longitude
        + "&datetime=" + datetime + "&provider=" + provider + "&guardianId=" + guardianId + "&cellInfos="
        + cellInfos + "&timestamp=" + timestamp + "&battery=" + battery;

RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();

try {
    // success
    return rest.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);
} catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
    // new Error Response
    return ResponseEntity.status(e.getStatusCode()).headers(e.getResponseHeaders())
            .body(e.getResponseBodyAsString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For making it to work using `HashMap` try this:-

```
List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<>();
messageConverters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
```

***Explanation***

By default RestTemplate sets a number of MessageConverters like below in the constructor

```
this.messageConverters.add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
this.messageConverters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
this.messageConverters.add(new ResourceHttpMessageConverter(false));
this.messageConverters.add(new SourceHttpMessageConverter<>());
this.messageConverters.add(new AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter());
```

And also it adds automatically `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` but that is after `AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter`

which doesn't work(very strange) because `AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter` takes over and returns before `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` could have actually worked

```
if (jackson2Present) {
    this.messageConverters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
}
```

And the class `AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter` extends `FormHttpMessageConverter` which is implementing the  `HttpMessageConverter<MultiValueMap<String, ?>>`, **here `MultiValueMap` is something to note**.

While in the case of `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` it extends `AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter` which is further extending the `AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter<Object>` and **note `Object` here**

Comment: It is using `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` by default. No need to set it explicitly. See first log for 400 Bad Request.

Comment: it worked in my case, very strange. can you share the bit of that code?

Comment: `final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<>();
messageConverters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
Map<String, Object> uriVariables = new HashMap<>();
uriVariables.put("param1", "1");
restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/demo-1/test", uriVariables, String.class);
`

Comment: No, it's request url, "param1" is request parameter.